# Purposfully timeout a PHP script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, timeout

this may seem odd, but I actually need a PHP script that WILL time-out, i.e.: take so long to execute that Apache WILL time-out the script and fire a 408 error.

The purpose for this, is to demo capturing the 408 with a custom 408 error page to report timeouts to a database.

Perhaps there is a better way to do this that you may suggest?

I don't think an infinite loop would work as Apache would 500 if I remember correctly.

Edit -------

It has been pointed out that a 408 is a client error, so in addition, what error would Apache fire if a script times-out?

I'd like an actual example rather than a synthesized `header()` as this is to be pitched to a client and they would ideally like a real-world example.

Thank you!

Comment: Test which error apache will throw with an overly long script: `<?php set_time_limit(1); sleep(2); ?>`. Am I understanding you correctly, that you want the client to timeout?

Comment: I would like to catch the timeout (either on the server or client) and serve a custom error decument. I'll try your example above :) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 408 is a [client error](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> 408 Request Timeout
>
> The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait.

So you'll have to `telnet <yourhost> 80` and just sit and wait. Of course you can emulate this through [`fsockopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) if you want to do it programmatically.

Throwing the header from code might also work.

Comment: What error would Apache give then if it timed-out the request? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

How about sending 408 status code from php script?

```
<?php
  header("HTTP/1.0 408 Request Timeout");
?>
```

Or perhaps

```
<?php 
  sleep(99999);
?>
```

Comment: Though old, this is actually (along with the while true) a good answer. For me it was, as I wanted to check ajax behavior, calling this script.

Comment: Onlt the while(true) is a good answer. Server returning timeout is an actual response. A timeout as clients generally have to deal with means that the server does NOT respond in the timeframe that the client expects. It does not entail an error code.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    while(true){
        //to infinity and beyond...
    }
?>
```

This will do it..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the page to actually timeout.  If you're just testing, you can just tell PHP to output an 408 code in the header:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 408 Request Timeout");
exit;
```